# Selenium Grid how to get file from it with Java?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-grid

I have Selenium Grid on remote machine with IP. One of my test cases has to download the file and in assertion I want to compare the name of downloaded file, also in another test case I have to import file to application from Windows. 
How to do that in Java?
Selenium Grid is on Windows Server 2008.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I'm aware that's not possible with selenium alone. You might be able to get browser logs, but what I do is enable file access to a shared server and check that the file is downloaded there. First I set Chrome's download directory:

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
prefs.put("download.default_directory", "\\remote-ip\path\to\download\directory");
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://gridhubhost:4444/wd/hub"), capabilities);
```

Then after the test makes the browser download the file I check the filesystem on the remote server:

```
File downloadedFile = new File("\\remote-ip\path\to\download\directory\file");
assertEquals(downloadedFile.getName(), "expected-name");
```

[edit]: you might be better off asserting the file exists, e.g:

```
assertTrue(downloadedFile.exists());
```

Comment: thank you very much, it works for me perfectly, I thought that I wille have to configure putty and ssh connection between machines.

Comment: Hmm, doesn't this just assert that the file's name is the same one as you specified in the new File(String path) constructor?

Comment: Ugh, I think you're right /facepalm. Might also need to assert the file exists.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the downloaded file exists in the path Using `java.io.File`:

```
File f = new File(filePathString);
if(f.exists() && !f.isDirectory()) { 
   Sustem.out.printLn("File is downloaded");
}
```

also, if you want to import then you'll have to check whether there exists an editable Input field for file import, if yes then you can directly use sendkeys as per below:

```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("upload input path")).sendKeys("C:/Users/1.pdf");
```

otherwise you'll have to make use of AutoIt or Robot class if upload link opens windows dialogs.